# Azure Function to Generate file from JSON contentByte - Microsoft Graph API Email generation

Tags: python, azure, function

Im having problem writting an azure function which takes blob input (JSON) and create a file using the contentbyte column from the JSON file.

JSON Template:

```
{
   "@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('XXX.com')/messages('AQMkADAA3D%3D')/attachments",
   "value":[
      {
         "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
         "@odata.mediaContentType":"application/pdf",
         "id":"AQMkADA0NjA5YT",
         "lastModifiedDateTime":"2023-06-29T14:40:33Z",
         "name":"MISC.pdf",
         "contentType":"application/pdf",
         "size":314000,
         "isInline":false,
         "contentId":"5E2D20ED5265174C8C9DC1AD59FFA4outlook.com",
         "contentLocation":null,
"contentBytes":"JVBERi0xLjYNCiWAgYKDDQoxIDAgb2JqDQo8PCAvQ3JlYXRvciA8Pg0KL0NyZWF0aW9uRGF0ZSA8NDQzYTM[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQJSz.png)y"
      }
   ]
}
```

Azure Function:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwHNK.png)

Below is the azure function i wrote:

```
import json
import base64
from base64 import *
import logging
import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest,inputBlob: func.InputStream, outputBlob: func.Out[bytes]) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    try:
 
        with open(inputBlob.read(),encoding='utf-8-sig') as user_file:
            file_contents = user_file.read()
            contents = json.loads(file_contents)
            
        for file_contents in enumerate(contents.get("value")):
            outputBlob.set(base64.b64decode(content.get("contentBytes")))
        
        output = {"run":"success"}
        return json.dumps(output)
     except Exception as ex:
        logging.exception(ex)
        output =  {"run":"failure"}   
        return json.dumps(output)
```

Below is the error msg"

```
[Error]   [Errno 36] File name too long: b'{\r\n   "@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(\'fsdja@eadft.com\')/messages(\'AQMkADA0NjA5YTMyLWU4MDctNDZkMi04
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> function which takes blob input (JSON) and create a file using the contentbyte column from the JSON file.

- "File name too long," typically occurs when you attempt to create a file with a name that exceeds the maximum allowed length for file names, `Ensure that the file name is not too long and does not contain any illegal characters.`
- I have created Http trigger function with runtime stack python. I am able to create a file of content byte and sent to storage container by using output binding like below:

**function code:**

```
import azure.functions as func
import logging
import base64

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.route(route="http_trigger", methods=["POST"])
@app.blob_output(arg_name="output",
                path="pavan/pavan.pdf",
                connection="AzureWebJobsStorage")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest, output:func.Out[str]) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    try:
        req_body = req.get_json()
    except ValueError:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Invalid JSON input",
            status_code=400
        )

    if 'contentbyte' not in req_body:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Missing 'contentbyte' field in JSON",
            status_code=400
        )

    content_byte_base64 = req_body['contentbyte']

    # Decode base64 content byte
    try:
        content_bytes = base64.b64decode(content_byte_base64)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error decoding content byte: {str(e)}")
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Error decoding content byte",
            status_code=500
        )

    # Decode content if it's encoded
    if 'encoding' in req_body and req_body['encoding'] == 'base64':
        try:
            content_bytes = base64.b64decode(content_bytes)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Error decoding content: {str(e)}")
            return func.HttpResponse(
                "Error decoding content",
                status_code=500
            )

    # Write content to a file
    try:
        output.set(content_bytes)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error writing to file: {str(e)}")
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Error writing to file",
            status_code=500
        )

    return func.HttpResponse(
        "File created successfully",
        status_code=200
    )
```

- I have posting contentbyte of microsoft graph api throgh postman and created file successfully. check below:

[image]

[image]

The output file is sent to storage container successfully. check below:

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Pavan. Your code helped me to identify the mistake i made.
Below is the updated code I wrote which works great.

```
contents = json.loads(inputBlob.read()) 
for index,content in enumerate(contents.get("value")):
   fname = content.get("name")
   cbyte = content.get("contentBytes")
   conv_cbyte= base64.b64decode(cbyte)
   outputBlob1.set(conv_cbyte)
```

Now, I'm using the for loop because we have multiple JSON content in the file. So we may have multiple files. In the above case, since the OUPUT Blob I specified the file name, it continue to overwrite the Test.PDF file again and again. Can you please advise how to save the file with the name from the json?